# powershell to open a filename that is always changing

Tags: powershell

I"m trying to put my powershell script in windows task scheduler so I can schedule it to open up an excel file on a monthly basis, without needing my input.  The problem that I'm running in to is that the file name changes every month with an updated date.  So how do I have a powershell script to open up the correct file?

My current script is as follows:

`$objectExcel = new-object -c excel.application
    $objectExcel.displayAlerts=$false
    $objectExcel.visible=$FALSE
    $main=$objectExcel.workbooks.open("P:\report.xlsm")`

This opens an xlsm file called Report.

In March, when I update the report, I will rename it Report201702.  When I update the report in April, I will rename it Report201703.

How do I write my powershell script so it automatically also append the dateformat in the file name, or a way for me to always get the most recent file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Get-Date with custom formatting

```
$report = "report{0}.xlsm" -f (Get-Date -format yyyyMM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, find the newest file save the name to a variable and open that.

```
$report = Get-ChildItem P:\*.xlsm | sort lastwritetime | select -Last 1
$main = $objectExcel.workbooks.open($report.fullname)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, what does this do exactly?  To be more specific,  Here's what I did.  Is this correct? 

Sorry, I'm new to scripting.



Set-executionpolicy remotesigned
$objectExcel = new-object -c excel.application
$objectExcel.displayAlerts=$false
$objectExcel.visible=$FALSE
$report = Get-ChildItem "P:\Data Requests\Report Automations"\*.xlsm | sort lastwritetime | select -last 1
$main=$objectExcel.workbooks.open($report.fullname) 

(sorry.  dont know how to edit the formatting when I reply)

Comment: `Set-executionpolicy` is a persistent setting, shouldn't be in the script. For testing I'd remove `$objectExcel.visible=$FALSE`  Otherwise you will have to test yourself ;-)

Comment: :). Thanks.  I wanted to know what the code that BenH suggested does,  and whether I applied it correctly to my script.

Comment: This code finds the `.xlsm` file that was written to last and saves the object to the variable `$report`. Then in the line that opens the workbook, calls on the `fullname` property from the variable, which will be the full path of the file to open.